# Is there a GruntJS task that will build a JS closure from a source code template?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, closures

I need a way to organize source code for a third-party javascript widget; it's one big closure with a single variable in the host site's namespace.  This widget will be contained in a single js module/closure.  Something like jQuery is built using an intro.js and outro.js and this creates loads of invalid javascript.  For instance, the intro.js file from jQuery:

```
(function() {
```

What I need is a way to make a file that might look like this:

```
var _ns || _ns = (function() {
  /* --include(src/module1.js)-- */
  /* --include(src/module2.js)-- */
  return { pub: api };
});
```

Is there a GruntJS task for something like this?  This is different than concat/uglify, etc.  I know that with concat I can do it the way the jQuery team does.  I'm trying to avoid that.  Also, I can't use requireJS because it requires polluting the host site's js namespace.

Googling this is very difficult as there are some very popular conflicting results.

Comment: Exactly my question, thanks for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout [Grunt-wrap](https://github.com/chrissrogers/grunt-wrap) it does exactly that.